# unix shell script exexution invokes a new jvm

Tags: java, shell, unix

Scenario : The jars are deployed on unix environment, which are used to execute batch process using shell script, and in these n shell scripts the environment path(read classpath) is setup first(before running every shell script).

My question is : is a new JVM created when ever a shell script is executed

Edit:
Thanks user000001 for the answer
one more question : Is this not a costly affair, as creating a new JVM on every new script call and destroying of that jvm instance on finish of every script. Is there a efficient way or work around to this

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is. Every time you invoke the `java` command from the script, a new JVM is created.

Comment: one more question : Is this not a costly affair, as creating a new JVM on every new script call and destroying of that jvm instance on finish of every script. Is there a efficient way or work around to this

Comment: invoke other jars from the first jar invoked by shell script that way only one jvm is launched